# Passing filename arguments from Bash to Perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell

I'm working on my University assignment and I've stumbled upon an issue I can't fix by myself, perhaps somebody here will be able to help, since I'm out of ideas...

I have to pass filenames specified as a list of arguments passed to my main script (Bash) and later process these files in another script (Perl).

This is how I am doing it in Bash:

```
perl DisplayGroupedByArtist.pl "$@"
```

Then in perl I iterate over the files like that:

```
my @files = @ARGV;
foreach $file (@files)
{
  #some stuff here
}
```

The problem is - it's working just fine as long as I don't invoke the script from outside the directory.

```
test/bash_script.sh Samples/*.mp3
```

Then, instead of something like "Samples/01 Lycia - Frozen.mp3 Samples/01 Slowdive - Alison.mp3 Samples/01 The Cure - Plainsong.mp3", the value passed to my Perl script is simply "Samples/*.mp3".

I guess it's worth mentioning that in my Bash script I have this line to ensure that I'm invoking Perl script from the correct directory:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
```

**Update:**
To make things clear: The main problem here is the fact that if I run the script like `bash_script.sh *.mp3` - it passes the file list to Perl script with no issues, whilst if I execute it like `test/bash_script.sh *.mp3`, the value passed to Perl is simply a string "*.mp3", not a list of files.

Comment: And what happens if you remove the `cd` line?

Comment: If I do so, then "perl DisplayGroupedByArtist.pl" is not going to work at all, returning "Can't open perl script "DisplayGroupedByArtist.pl": No such file or directory".

Comment: Fix the path to the script, then. `perl "$(dirname "$0")"/DisplayGroupedByArtist.pl "$@"`.

Comment: Unfortunately - doesn't fix the problem. Still the exact same behaviour.

Comment: Which behaviour? No such file or directory, or not finding the files?

Comment: Not finding the files - acts exactly the same as with cd line.

Comment: It's the shell that expands wildcards, so you must use the correct path to the files. Otherwise, the shell won't expand them, and Perl will see the asterisk. If you want to expand a wildcard in Perl, see [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob).

Comment: Thank you for the link. But what I don't get is - why does it work with no issues, expanding the asterisk and passing files to Perl, if I execute the bash script from its directory and doesn't work in the case I explained in my post...

Comment: The `bash` script never sees `*.mp3` if the pattern matches; it sees the list of files that `*.mp3` expands *to* after the calling shell processes it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust the argument; `Samples/*.mp3` is relative to where the script is called *from*, not to the location of the script.

```
tests/bash_script.sh ../Samples/*.mp3
```

Comment: The problem is... my teacher expects the script to work exactly the same in both situations:

test/bash_script.sh *.mp3

and

cd test
bash_script.sh *.mp3

Comment: Are you sure? This is standard unix behaviour. Your teacher may be assuming this is equivalent.

Comment: Unfortunately I am... He sent me a message saying that he wants to run it like: test/bash_script.sh *.mp3 and expects it to list mp3 files from test directory.

Comment: Then you need to either quote the pattern and have your `bash` script concatenate it with the correct directory and expand it (which, frankly, is not something you can safely do in `bash`), or pass the concatenated directory/pattern to the Perl script (which does have a function for expanding a glob). `test/bash_script '*.mp3'`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The main problem here though is the fact that if I run the script like `bash_script.sh *.mp3` - it passes the file list to Perl script with no issues, whilst if I execute it like `test/bash_script.sh *.mp3`, the value passed to Perl is simply a string "*.mp3", not a list of files.

Comment: @Jakub: That's because before running the command, shell tries to expand the wildcards.

Comment: Re "*the value passed to Perl is simply a string "*.mp3", not a list of files*", Exactly. You don't want to pass a list of files to `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Perl problem, but a problem of the calling shell. Assuming that your shell is bash (but note that your teacher's shell might be something differently), a wild card pattern such as Samples/*.mp3 is usually expanded by the shell into a list of files; now what exactly happens if no file matches the pattern, depends on the shell and how it is configured. For example, the default in bash is that the string representing a pattern is passed unchanged to the application, but the shell could also be configured so that the pattern is simply removed, or that an error message is printed.

You have no idea how the teacher's shell is configured, and if your teacher uses a different shell from bash, the behaviour might even be different.

When you define an interface to a program, you never specify "how it is typed in the calling shell", because this doesn't mean much. You specify, what parameters the program accepts (i.e. the contents of ARGV) and how the these parameters affect the execution of the program. What the caller (yourself, or the teacher) exactly has to type so that your program receives the arguments in the correct form, is **not** part of an interface specification.

For example, you can allow relative pathes to be passed, and define a search order where to look for the files. You can also allow that the strings passed to your command contain wildcards. You can even allow regular expressions or what else comes to your mind, but never forget: You have no access to the sequence of characters, which the caller has actually typed, so you can't do any interpretation on them.